# Boot Menu Screwed up, computer won't boot

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I've been using Ubuntu to for years now, I'm an EE and love the system. This week I was having trouble with Ubuntu so I decided to do a fresh install parallel with Win XP.  The install crashed midstream and now I can not boot at all. I believe all I need to do is repair the `grub.cfg` file, or maybe another file?

So, I booted from my liveCD and went into the file structure and everything seems intact, However, the `grub.cfg` file looks like it's a mess. I don't remember how to gain access to GRUB via permissions. I did it once before a year ago.

Any one with any ideas?

Comment: You're an EE? You might be interested in [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I would suggest.

1. Boot from live CD.
2. Locate the previous Ubuntu partition and [mount](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man2/mount.2.php) it.
3. [chroot](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/chroot.1.php) into the mounted partition.
4. Run the [grub-install](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man8/grub-install.8.php) command.

Exact commands may vary depending upon your partitions and directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could just install Ubuntu again. The installer will ask you if you want to overwrite Ubuntu and install alongside Windows; you should choose that option. It will install Grub properly.

If you simply decide to repair Grub now, you will probably wind up with a half-baked Linux installation.